# How come weight doesn't affect the rebound height on a net?

Tags: forces, energy, work

According to my text book two unequal masses, (80kg and 50kg) fall on a net and the work done by that net is calculated by $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$. This work is then transformed into kinetic energy for both masses and then finally back to gravitational potential energy once the full rebound height is reached: $m_1gh$ and $m_2gh$.

My book claims that weight does not affect the height of the rebound! How is this possible mathematically? Wouldn't the kinetic energies of these masses be different and therefore the height?

Please help :)

Answer (score 3):

Neglecting friction, if you let a body fall from a certain height, it has a certain amount of potential energy. This energy can be transformed in other energies, e.g. in your example into kinetic energy (it falls down), then into potential energy of the net (at its lowest point), back into kinetic energy (it springs up again) and finally back to potential energy (at its highest point).

Since energy is conserved and we don't lose any energy by friction, the energy in the body will always be the same. The body will jump up and down forever, having always the same maximal height.

This is true for any body, independent of its mass. Therefore, if we let fall two bodies, they will both move up and down forever, always at the same height.

The energy of a heavy body at the same height will be higher, its kinetic energy will be higher, too (but the velocity will be the same), but the net will strain more.

How to understand this mathematically? Well, there's not much to understand mathematically, it's just physics! If we want to use mathematics, you can start with energy conservation

$$ E_A = E_E $$

where $E_A$ is the energy at the beginning and $E_E$ the energy at the end. But $E_A = mgh_1$ and in the end we will have only potential energy as well, so it's also $E_E = mgh_2$, since $m$ and $g$ don't change. Here $h_1$ is the height at the beginning and $h_2$ the height at the end (we pretend to not know that they are the same by considerations above). But then

$$ mgh_1 = mgh_2 $$
$$ h_1 = h_2 $$

The mass cancels, the only thing that affects $h_2$, is actually $h_1$. So if you have two bodies, both with the same $h_1$, they'll also have the same $h_2$ (and in fact $h_1 = h_2$).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Equivalence Principle (EP), that mass and weight are in constant proportion for all masses.  Any "advantage" enjoyed by the heavier body is exactly canceled by its greater mass.  All local material bodies vacuum free fall identically, along minimum action trajectories. Primary divergences in your case are air resistance and anelasticity of the net.

http://www.npl.washington.edu/eotwash/epwhat

The EP is hot stuff.  Its implied vacuum symmetries define the whole of physics.  Einstein's elevators, pendulums, Newton (the opening to *Philosophiae Naturalis Principia Mathematica*), Galileo...Philoponus dropping stuff in 500 AD.  There is no measurable property that violates the EP, including pulsar binaries with solar stars or white dwarfs, to at least 14 significant figures,

arXiv:1304.6875 
 
*Science* 340(6131) 448 (2013) 
 
*Physics Today* 66(7) 14 (2013)

Now, the fun part!  There is a singular property that can be observed and calculated but not measured.  The EP has never been tested against it, for it is an emergent property that is "obviously" irrelevant.  You have it with you right now - two pairs of obvious examples.  Can the EP fall to a footnote?